# Scpiy: strange behavior of scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: python, scipy

I'm doing a minization using `scipy.optimize.minimize`.

In its looking for proper argument `x0` for my target function `f(x0)`, the `x0` has a sudden change, and the value turns into `NaN`, so the `minimize` method stopped.

Here is the `x0` and `result` series before the strange behaviro:

```
[ 0.1329492   0.13074885 -9.92951618 -1.15521653  5.74419133  4.11687514
  0.19983624 -9.95148156 -1.18517543  5.69420641  3.91303028  0.19983624
 -7.34387457 -5.30116147  4.90141309  5.06593156  0.18205401] 267.765197762
[ 0.1329492   0.13074885 -9.92951618 -1.15521653  5.74419133  4.11687514
  0.19983624 -9.95148156 -1.18517543  5.69420641  3.91303028  0.19983624
 -7.34387457 -5.30116149  4.9014131   5.06593156  0.18205401] 267.76519813
[ 0.1329492   0.13074885 -9.92951618 -1.15521653  5.74419133  4.11687514
  0.19983624 -9.95148156 -1.18517543  5.69420641  3.91303028  0.19983624
 -7.34387457 -5.30116149  4.90141309  5.06593157  0.18205401] 267.765196949
[ 0.1329492   0.13074885 -9.92951618 -1.15521653  5.74419133  4.11687514
  0.19983624 -9.95148156 -1.18517543  5.69420641  3.91303028  0.19983624
 -7.34387457 -5.30116149  4.90141309  5.06593156  0.18205402] 267.765198923
[  5.93742471e-01   4.06257529e-01  -5.09322593e+00   1.73303924e+00
   3.56252177e+00   2.98573010e+00   1.26090655e-09  -4.85059563e+00
   1.22511256e+00   4.81903606e+00   2.51934646e+00   5.72130981e-10
  -1.06593289e+01   2.76365721e+00   4.63158974e+00   6.86179361e+00
   1.29879685e-09] nan
```

After chaning around `[ 0.1329492   0.13074885 ...`, the `x0` suddenly change to `[  5.93742471e-01   4.06257529e-01 ...`, and returns `NaN`.

The strange thing is, the target method `f(x0)` can return a value with the last `x0`(`[  5.93742471e-01   4.06257529e-01 ...]`).

I really have no idea what to do with this.

Comment: Being able to see the objective function and parameters specified in `minimize` would be helpful, (e.g. what is the `method` (have you tried others) and did you set any `bounds`)

Comment: It sounds like you're thinking the problem is related to wild fluctuations in sample values; setting the `bounds` parameter might prove useful

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what the reason would be because I don't have the target function or the call to scipy.optimize.minimize() but what I can see is this:

The first and the second-to last x are different by only 1*10^-8, in two of the components. That seems like extremely little.

If you did not specify otherwise, `minimize` decides based on whether you specified constraints (have a look at the doc string). There's a good chance you end up with BFGS or similar, which is based on gradients. Now, if you tried to construct a gradient based on the first few evaluations, I can see how that would lead to crazy results with such a small spacing.

The question is: Did you maybe do something that led to these small starting intervals? Did you specify the algorithm to use? Did you specify any bounds which might have triggered the small initial intervals? Generally, do not set bounds unless there's a good reason not to go someplace. Many people will set bounds merely on the basis of "I don't think there are good solutions here" -- that's a bad habit and has confused many an algorithm!

For a better analysis, you should post some more information.
Depending on your problem, you might find that a least-squares method or a simplex optimizer may be better, maybe even a genetic algorithm, given the number of input variables.